# How to load PHP class dynamically with namespace

Tags: php

Here is my static code -

```
$tireBrick = new DataObject\Objectbrick\Data\classname($object);
```

What I need is, I need to change "classname" into variable (dynamically load the class)

```
`$tireBrick = new DataObject\Objectbrick\Data\$brickName($object);`  //But php doesn't allow to use this syntax.
```

As you can see it'll dynamically assign "`$brickName($object)`"

Can anyone help me to load this class dynamically?

Thanks,
Tharanga.

Comment: Have you read [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) in the PHP documentation ?

Comment: Store a full classname into a string and call new $var($obj)

Answer (score 0):

```
$tireBrick = "new DataObject\\Objectbrick\\Data\\".$brickName($object);
```

Or try to learn about namespace to shorten it

Answer (score 0):

Use `::class` to get the full classname:

```
$myClass = classname::class; // DataObject\Objectbrick\Data\classname

$tireBrick = new $myClass($object);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a bunch of spellchecker classes solved with this. It looks like this:

```
$baseClass = 'SpellChecker';
$activeChecker = $activeChecker ? 'Hun' : Yii::$app->params['spellChecker']['active'];
$spellCheckerClass = "common\\models\\spellchecker\\$activeChecker$baseClass";
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
/** @var SpellChecker $spellChecker */
$spellChecker = new $spellCheckerClass();
```

Now the essence of the whole thing is it's the best if you use similar classes, so you can use the functions without being afraid of them crashing the app if the function not exists. For this you can implement an observer model, where you define every function you want to use in the observer class and then you create child classes where you overwrite the functionality of the observer class.